# how do I create a feature class from a table?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I have a database table that has the column and types defined. But it's a database table. I need a feature class so I can add spatial functionality, like add a SHAPE field. How do I create a feature class from a database table?

Update - I'm starting from a database table. The destination is an existing feature class in my enterprise SDE. I need to take some fields from the table and build a value for a SHAPE field. I also need to be able to use my fieldmappings to map fields from the source to the destination; hence the need to get this data into a feature class instead of a table.

Comment: Does your table **not** have spatial info already?  Like you don't have a WKT or something stored in there, correct?  Also, where did the data come from?

Comment: @Branco correct. I'm using some of the fields from the row to build my SHAPE field.

Comment: Points/lines/polygons?

Comment: @Branco - points for now. This may change to include lines and polygons in the future.

Comment: Look at this (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000001z000000) for your points.  For the lines/polygon part, it would be a little more tricky but doable I believe.

Comment: Please **update the question** in response to clarification comments, including:  What RDBMS and *exact* version are  you using?  What geometry storage type (e.g. SDEBINARY, native RDBMS type, SDE.ST_Geometry,...) do you desire to have in the table?  How large is the existing table (in rows)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JoinField_management to join the table in which you have the schema to the Feature Class that has no fields defined. If you join by OBJECT_ID, the Feature Class will receive all the fields from the join table.

Details and code block for this solution as well as an alternative solution you can find here:

[Creating geodatabase feature class using geodatabase table schema with ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87124/how-to-create-a-geodatabase-feature-class-using-a-geodatabase-table-schema-with)